# Storing daily data in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, tracking

so I am aware of .plist and archives and SQLLite as methods to store persistent data within the app, however, I have been stuck for a while trying to figure out how to store data from a user's daily activity so it may be displayed in a graph. For example, if a user walks 1 mile one day and 3 the next, how would one go about knowing when its one day and when it's the next?

THe best I can come up with is to store the current date, then the next time the user performs an action, check if the stored date is the same as the current date and if it's not, then save the data for a different day.

Has anyone got any better ideas or is there a standard way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Save the info in a DB when it's gathered.  Timestamp the entries.  Is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a SQLLite DB with a timestamp column indicating when the entry has been written. With NSDateComponents you can figure out later which day the entry has been added.

When you create an index over the timestamp column your queries will be pretty fast, what's kind of perfect for drawing graphs...

Answer (score 0):

Using NSDate is a perfectly fine way. You'll probably need the dates for the graph anyways, or?

Answer (score 0):

SQLLite is still a great method for that.  Just don't treat it like a flat file.
SQLLite supports time stamping. Each time you enter the data you can add that stamp to the field.  Running a simple SQL query will give you your data in a format you can use for a graph. You can also query the database to see what the current data is or how long it has been since data was last entered.

Read this page for a few hints:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the right data structure for this, just store your data and timestamp in an array. Next time when you update, check the timestamp of last object in the array and see if the data has changed. If yes, add a new entry.

To persist this, just save this array into a PList. Since it's not a lot of data PList won't be a bad idea.